# If name attribute is X then get content of value attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am struggling with code in C# for getting value depending on the first argument from XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <Parameter name="browserVersion" value="101.0"/>
        <Parameter name="os" value="WIN11"/>
        <Parameter name="build" value=""/>
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

I would like to check if the parameter name is browser then take its content from **value**.
I am able to get this values by `SelectNodes("//@value")` and `node[0].Value` but I am wondering if there is another way of getting those values without specifing the position. Here is my code:

```
var filename = @"../../../browser.runsettings";
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(filename);

            XmlNodeList node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//@value");
            var browserValue = node[0].Value;
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Have you considered deserializing the XML to a model class?

Comment: może `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter[@name='browser']/@value")?.Value` ?

Comment: Thanks for that @Selvin! I worked my code around your response and I have this:
`public string getValueFromName(string name)
        {
            var filename = @"../../../browser.runsettings";
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(filename);

            return xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode($"//Parameter[@name='{name}']/@value").Value;
        }`
I am still checking how it is behaving performance wise

Comment: dodaj ten `?` .. inaczej jak nie będzie węzła to `SelectSingleNode` zwróci `null` i a jak wiadomo "`null.Value`" rzuci wyjątkiem `NullRefferenceException` ... z pytajnikiem zwróci całość jako `null`

Comment: bonus: `doc.SelectNodes("//Parameter").OfType<XmlElement>().ToDictionary(e=>e.Attributes["name"].Value, e=>e.Attributes["value"].Value)` would retun `Dictionary<string, string>` with "name"/"value" attributes values as key/value

Comment: @Selvin I get that the both of you are speaking the same language. SO is explicitly english, though and others would appreciate understanding your comments, too. So, _no offense_ but please keep it in english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cycle thought them and check if the name is Browser and then use the value. Something like this should do it

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Name != "Browser") continue;
                
                browserValue = node.Value;
                break;
            }
```

Comment: var value = nodes!.Cast<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name == "Browser")?.Value;

Same foreach but cooler and simpler : )

Answer (score 0):

You can also get single node by using `.SelectSingleNode()` instead of using `.SelectNodes()`

```
var filename = @"../../../browser.runsettings";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//@value");
var browserValue = node.Value;
```